# Install crudini tool using homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am able to install `crudini` using `apt-get install crudini` on ubuntu, but on OSX I cannot install it using Homebrew because it is not found. Is there any way for me to install this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

crudini is a pip/python package. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crudini/

You can install it with `pip2 install crudini`.
`pip2` refers to homebrew's version of pip.